# No module named wtforms.compat

Tags: python, wtforms

While we are trying to execute with python 3.6.8 version getting below module error

```
from wtforms.compat import string_types, text_type
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms.compat'
```

when i tried installing or upgrading wtforms still it shows the same error

Can any one pls suggest

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Noticed this error today while running our Airflow 1.10.12 builds:

```
from wtforms.compat import text_type
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms.compat'
```

Apparently, the issue has to do with the latest version of `wtforms` released yesterday (3.0.0). We managed to get around it by pinning it to the previous version: `wtforms==2.3.3`.

Editing just to add more information: `compat.py` was completely removed once support for Python < 3.6 was dropped (see [PR](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/pull/554/files)). If you are running Python >= 3.6, you can also work with the latest `wtforms` by simply using `str` instead of `text_type` and `string_types`, since those were just aliases:

```
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    text_type = str
    string_types = (str,)
    izip = zip
```

And the imports should not be needed anymore.

If running Python < 3.6, you may need to stick with `wtforms<=2.3.3`.

Comment: @I have one more doubt, can i ask ?

Comment: Yeah, what's up @Ravi?

Comment: what are all the airflow metadata tables which has relation to pickle protocol.  We are facing unsupported pickle protocol 5 issue.. Could you pls suggest the tables

Comment: Hi. running airflow 1.10.14 and facing the same issue. How can I pin wtforms to the previous version: wtforms==2.3.3 ?

Comment: edit:
pip3 install wtforms==2.3.3

did the trick